# Instrument existing golang struct

Tags: go

Go's standard library has the `*net.Resolver` type, that is a struct, and I'd like to wrap it in some way because I want to collect metrics on DNS lookups for my application.

I tried wrapping `*net.Resolver`:

```
func WrapResolver(resolver *net.Resolver) *net.Resolver {
    return &instrumentedResolver{
        Resolver: resolver,
    }
}

type instrumentedResolver struct {
    *net.Resolver
}
```

But this doesn't work as `*instrumentedResolver` is not compatible with `*net.Resolver`. So, question is, is this possible? If it isn't is there any other way for me to collect these metrics?

Comment: Resolution is done through the `Dial` functions, and the `Resolver` has a `Dial` field. Can you not get what you want by hooking into that function?

Comment: No, the `Dial` function returns the connection that will be used to talk to the DNS server, I want metrics on the DNS operations separately, not on how long it takes to connect to the DNS server.

Comment: "connect to the DNS server"? Are you always trying to use dns over tcp or https? Still, the `Dial`/`DialContext` functions are how pretty much everything hooks into resolution. Can you provide whatever is making calls you want to instrument with a custom Dialer, which could use your own resolver? A lot of projects also use external package when they need more control over dns operation, like `https://github.com/miekg/dns`.

Comment: Again, the `Dial` function at `*net.Resolver` is used to create a connection to the DNS server. I want to collect metrics on how long methods like `*net.Dialer.LookupHost` take, hence I need to wrap `*net.Dialer` in some way.

Comment: yes, but the entrypoint for almost everything is a `Dial` or `DialContext` function, so that's your hook. Since it's a function type, you can supply whatever you want there, including a function that uses your resolver for name name resolution. As you've seen, `*net.Resolver` isn't an interface, so to hook into its internals, you need to use your own Dialer+Resolver implementation entirely.

Comment: Record start time in `Dial` and finish time in wrapped `Conn.Close` will mostly do the job.

Comment: See https://golang.org/issue/12503

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's either use miekg/dns or just wait for them to come up with a better solution.